# Conditional formatting in display template in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, javascript, search, content-type, content-search-web-part

I have a Content Search Web Part (CSWP) that lists two different content-types from a different application.

I would really like to be able to make the CSWP show content-type A in green and content-type B in red.

I tried to look at creating a display template for it, but I can't seem to crack the necessary JavaScript code.

Have anyone tried this setup or know how to set it up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes we can achieve this using display templates.

First if you are using an OOB display template, I would suggest make a copy of it in and customize it based on your requirement.

Now as you have a hold of a custom display template, **Make sure you map ContentType field in ManagedPropertyMapping**

something like below in your display template

```
&#39;Line 2&#39;{Line 2}:&#39;ContentType&#39;
```

Now in the html section you just need to check content type value and give css to the div or any element which populates content type name

```
<!--#_
if(line2 == "ContentTypeA")
    {
_#-->
            <div class="ms-noWrap" style="background-color:green">_#= line2 =#_</div>
<!--#_
}else if(line2 == "ContentTypeB"){
_#-->
            <div class="ms-noWrap" style="background-color:red">_#= line2 =#_</div>

<!--#_
}
_#-->
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: No Problem.. Happy to help :)